# How to compute P-value and standard error from correlation analysis of R's cor()

Tags: r, correlation

I have [data](http://dpaste.com/1064360/plain/) that contain 54 samples for each condition (x and y).
I have computed the correlation the following way:

```
> dat <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/1064360/plain/",header=TRUE)
> cor(dat$x,dat$y)
[1] 0.2870823
```

Is there a native way to produce SE of correlation in  R's cor() functions above
and p-value from T-test?

As explained in this [web](http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/gerstman/StatPrimer/correlation.pdf) (page 14.6)

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `?cor.test` instead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think that what you're looking for is simply the `cor.test()` function, which will return everything you're looking for except for the standard error of correlation. However, as you can see, the formula for that is very straightforward, and if you use `cor.test`, you have all the inputs required to calculate it.

Using the data from the example (so you can compare it yourself with the results on page 14.6):

```
> cor.test(mydf$X, mydf$Y)

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  mydf$X and mydf$Y
t = -5.0867, df = 10, p-value = 0.0004731
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.9568189 -0.5371871
sample estimates:
       cor 
-0.8492663
```

If you wanted to, you could also create a function like the following to include the standard error of the correlation coefficient.

For convenience, here's the equation:

[image]

*r* = the correlation estimate and *n* - 2 = degrees of freedom, both of which are readily available in the output above. Thus, a simple function could be:

```
cor.test.plus <- function(x) {
  list(x, 
       Standard.Error = unname(sqrt((1 - x$estimate^2)/x$parameter)))
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
cor.test.plus(cor.test(mydf$X, mydf$Y))
```

Here, "mydf" is defined as:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Neighborhood = c("Fair Oaks", "Strandwood", "Walnut Acres",
  "Discov. Bay", "Belshaw", "Kennedy", "Cassell", "Miner", "Sedgewick", 
  "Sakamoto", "Toyon", "Lietz"), X = c(50L, 11L, 2L, 19L, 26L, 
  73L, 81L, 51L, 11L, 2L, 19L, 25L), Y = c(22.1, 35.9, 57.9, 22.2, 
  42.4, 5.8, 3.6, 21.4, 55.2, 33.3, 32.4, 38.4)), .Names = c("Neighborhood", 
  "X", "Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Citation needed for that equation, isn't it (1 - r^2)/sqrt(Degrees-of-Freedom) ? https://www.jstor.org/stable/2277400?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents or https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00220973.1956.11010555?journalCode=vjxe20

Answer (score 3):

Can't you simply take the test statistic from the return value? Of course the test statistic is the estimate/se so you can calc se from just dividing the estimate by the tstat:

Using `mydf` in the answer above:

```
r = cor.test(mydf$X, mydf$Y)
tstat = r$statistic
estimate = r$estimate
estimate; tstat

       cor 
-0.8492663 
        t 
-5.086732
```