# Create dataframe of correlation and p values using group_by then plot with error bars in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, correlation, errorbar, standard-error

I want to plot the correlation between several factors in my data set. If possible, I'd like to try to add error bars or whiskers to these plotted values. 
Prior to calculating the values, I first want to group them according to the values in one of the columns. I would like to use a tidyverse solution if possible. I am able to achieve half of this using `cor()`, but I don't know how to add an additional column that contains the p value.

I think the `iris` data set demonstrates what I'd like to do fairly well. The actual data uses a time series along the x axis. I have `spearman` specified because that's the correlation used in my analysis, not because it's the correct choice in the `iris` data set. I've seen some other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097453/how-to-compute-p-value-and-standard-error-from-correlation-analysis-of-rs-cor) suggesting the use of `cor.test` and pulling the values from that, but I'm not sure how that would be applied back to the bar chart to use as error bars. Here's the code to create the basic bar chart below.

***Edit*** I have changed my example from using the `mtcars` data set to the `iris` data set as I think it better reflects my data. While the initial answer to the question by jay.sf worked with the `mtcars` set and was greatly appreciated, it didn't work with my data set and the `iris` set threw the same errors I was having. Additionally, I hadn't stated this in the original, but a tidyverse solution is preferable, but not necessary.

I think that the answer I'm looking for might be contained here, but I'm still trying to work out the details: https://dominicroye.github.io/en/2019/tidy-correlation-tests-in-r/.

```
iristest <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(COR = cor(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width, method = "spearman", use="complete.obs"))

ggplot(data = iristest) +
  aes(x = Species, y = COR) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_minimal()
```

As it is, `iristest` provides this output:

```
    Species     COR
1   setosa      0.7553375
2   versicolor  0.5176060
3   virginica   0.4265165
```

I think ideally I'd like the output to have the p values added after the COR column.

```
    Species     COR          p-value
1   setosa      0.7553375    ###
2   versicolor  0.5176060    ###
3   virginica   0.4265165    ###
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using mostly tidyverse...

Here is the correlation done with Spearman:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RVAideMemoire)

iristest <-  iris %>%
+ group_by(Species) %>%
+ group_modify(~ glance(spearman.ci(.x$Sepal.Width, .x$Sepal.Length))


iristest
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   Species [3]
  Species    estimate conf.low.Inf conf.high.Sup method                     
  <fct>         <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>                      
1 setosa        0.755        0.599         0.857 Spearman's rank correlation
2 versicolor    0.518        0.251         0.724 Spearman's rank correlation
3 virginica     0.427        0.131         0.653 Spearman's rank correlation
```

Using ggplot...

```
ggplot(iristest, aes(x = Species, y = estimate)) 
+ geom_bar(stat="identity") 
+ geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=conf.low.Inf, ymax=conf.high.Sup), width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9))
```

[image: bar graph of correlation estimate by species]

Comment: Thanks for putting out a possible solution. I'm pretty sure that the p values between Pearson and Spearman correlations aren't interchangeable though. I think that the spearman p values need to be determined separately. I think cor.test provides both the Spearman's rho as well as p values, but the trick is figuring out how to pull that data.

Comment: I have reworked my answer to use RVAideMemoire's spearman.ci to hopefully get what you were after.

Comment: I think I finally have it! I was getting the following error: Error in spearman.ci(.x$Sepal.Width, .x$Sepal.Length, method = "spearman") : 
  unused argument (method = "spearman"). Pulling out the (method = "spearman") portion fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Corey, apologies for the unused argument but very glad you have your solution (now corrected for posterity). I learnt stuff too so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `cor.test` yields a list where actually everything is stored what you need. So just write a function that grabs the desired values. We can use `by` here, which yields a list, that we can `rbind` to get a matrix with perfect row names for plotting. The `do.call` is required for the `rbind` of the data frames of a list.

```
res <- do.call(rbind, by(iris, iris$Species, function(x) { 
  rr <- with(x, cor.test(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, method="pearson")) 
  return(c(rr$estimate, CI=rr$conf.int)) 
})) 
#                  cor       CI1       CI2
# setosa     0.7425467 0.5851391 0.8460314
# versicolor 0.5259107 0.2900175 0.7015599
# virginica  0.4572278 0.2049657 0.6525292
```

Note, that `method="spearman"` won't work with data with ties such as `iris`, so I used `"pearson"` here.

To plot the data I recommend `barplot` which comes with R. We store the bar locations `b <-` and use them as x-coordinates for the `arrows`. For the y-coordinates we take the values from our matrix.

```
b <- barplot(res[,1], ylim=c(0, range(res)[2]*1.1), 
             main="My Plot", xlab="cyl", ylab="Cor. Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width")
arrows(b, res[,2], b, res[,3], code=3, angle=90, length=.1)
abline(h=0)
box()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm having some difficulties with the actual data set. Running the first half of the code I get the error "second argument must be a list", for the do.call(rbind, by(df, df$column) portion. I tried adding in a "na.omit()" to the "mtcars$cyl" equivalent to see if that was tripping things up, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: @Corey Hmm, could you provide `dput(yourData[1:10, ])`?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share it right now :( Am I reading the error correctly in that for some reason R isn't seeing the "mtcars$cyl" section as a list? At least I would know if I'm hunting for the issue in the right area.

Comment: @Corey Do you actually mean the `mtcars` data? There should be no error. Have you tried a fresh R session without loading packages?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. No, running it through the mtcars data worked perfectly. Using the same process for my own data set is where I'm hitting the error. When I said "mtcars$cyl" I was referring to the equivalent in my data set, something like "mydf$ColumnFromMydf"

Comment: @Corey It's really hard to debug something imaginary, you could try other methods to make your issue reproducible, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: OK. I tried using the iris data set and I'm getting the same errors as I am with my actual data set. res <- do.call(rbind, by(iris, iris$Species, function(x) {
  rr <- with(x, cor.test(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, method="spearman"))
  return(c(rr$estimate, CI=rr$conf.int))
})) . It yeieds this: Error in do.call(rbind, by(iris, iris$Species, function(x) { : 
  second argument must be a list

Comment: @Corey Yeah, you set `method="spearman "` where I set `method="pearson"`, but you have ties in your data, so spearman won't work. May I ask for the reason why you used spearman in your analysis?

Comment: The data set isn't normally distributed, so I ruled Pearson out. That left Spearman's rho and Kendall's tau. Seems both of those throw the same error here....

Comment: Pearson doesn't seem to assume normality, though, see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3733/163114

Comment: Further down the link they state "Kowalski's analysis concludes that the distribution of r is not robust in the presence of non-normality and recommends alternative procedures." So even if normality isn't necessarily assumed, it doesn't deal with non-normal distributions and outliers well unfortunately :(

Comment: @Corey [This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/50072/163114) recommends `coin::spearman_test`, yields the p-value though. You actually could ask at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) how to calculate CIs for spearman correlation with ties, since this gets statistically challenging. For how to plot them you have my answer:)

Comment: @Corey Let me know when you have the solution, if you want, I am actually interested!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that achieves what is asked for.
Broken down into steps, it is slightly longer than the above examples. This version only uses base R though which may be of interest to some.

```
# Just extract the columns used in your question
data = iris[, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Species")]

# Group the data by species
grouped.data = by(data, (data$Species), list)
# Run the function 'cor.test' (from stats) over the data from each species
cor.results = lapply(grouped.data, function(x) cor.test(x$Sepal.Length, x$Sepal.Width, method = "spearman", exact = FALSE) )
# Extract the rho and p-value
rho = sapply(cor.results, "[[", "estimate"))
p = sapply(cor.results, "[[", "p.value")
# Bundle the results into a data.frame (or whatever data structure you prefer)
data.frame(Species = names(cor.results), COR = rho, `p-value` = p, row.names = NULL)
```

```
     Species       COR      p.value
1     setosa 0.7553375 2.316710e-10
2 versicolor 0.5176060 1.183863e-04
3  virginica 0.4265165 2.010675e-03
```

[See the note in `?cor.test` about the use of `exact = FALSE` which is necessary for these data.]